# Devexpress Gallery Control - Item click event

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have the following gallery control:

```
gallerycontrol.Gallery.ItemClick +=new GalleryItemClickEventHandler(Gallery_ItemClick);
private void Gallery_ItemClick(object sender, GalleryItemClickEventArgs e) {
}
```

**My question is : How can I pass another parameter like gallery item clicked's name** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on [GalleryItemClickEventArgs](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonGalleryItemClickEventArgsMembersTopicAll) there's an `Item` property you can access that references the item clicked, which in turn allows you to retrieve the name.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks for quick answer for my stupid question. I just find out before reading this.